# Pending Transaction with Low Gas

Tags: pending-transactions

I sent a test transaction unfortunately the gas was too low, I have tried overwriting this, But when I send It states (Error 13) Invalid Signed transaction?? 
If I knew what this meant maybe I could do something?

Also if low gas what inevitably happens?
1/ Run out of gas then im ok to send txs again
2/Transaction gets timed out?

Comment: always good to check https://ethstats.net/ to find the current gas price before sending a tx. Or use estimateGas function.